# How is the partial derivative with respect to normal related to the gradient of a scalar field?

Tags: vector-analysis, surfaces, surface-integrals, divergence-operator, divergence-theorem

I've been trying to understand the solution to a question based on the Gauss Divergence Theorem. The question says,

If $\phi$ is harmonic in $V$, then $\iint_{S} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial n} dS = 0$. (We need to prove this)

The solution goes like this, and I've added my comments too-

$\iint_{S} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial n} dS = \iint_{S} (\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial n}n).n dS$. This makes sense because $n$ is the unit normal.

$= \iint_{S} (\nabla \phi).n dS$ **I have trouble here. How can we write that $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial n}n = \nabla \phi$??**

$= \iiint_{V} div(\nabla \phi)dV$, by Divergence theorem, this step is clear

$=  \iiint_{V} \nabla^{2} \phi dV = 0$, since $\phi$ is harmonic in $V$, this step is clear too..

Can anybody please explain the second step to me? Firstly, if n is the normal, what do we even, which is a vector, what do we mean by taking a partial derivative with respect to it? Even if we do, won't that result in a vector rather than a scalar? How would that result in the gradient of the vector? I tried writing that $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial n} = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial n} + \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial n} + \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial n}$, but was unable to proceed. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: The real question here is: what does $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial n}$ mean? I would _define_ it as $\nabla\phi.n$, which makes your problem go away.

Comment: n seems to be the normal, since only then would we be able to use the Gauss Divergence theorem, right?